# Help needed with a proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let z: R-> R be a differentiable function such that z(x)>x^2. Prove that z'(x) is not bounded. I tried assuming that z'(x) is bounded and attempted to derive a contradiction, but now I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>z(0)>0$ be arbitrary.  Then $z(x) - z(0) > x^2 - z(0) > x^2-x$.  By the mean value theorem, there is some $c \in (0,x)$ such that $\displaystyle z^\prime(c) = \frac{z(x)-z(0)}{x-0} > \frac{x^2-x}{x} = x-1$.  Since $x$ can be as large as we like, it follows that $z^\prime(c)$ can be as large as we like, so $z^\prime$ is not a bounded function.

You can also do this by using the fundamental theorem of calculus and contradiction.  Suppose for contradiction that $z^\prime(x) < M$ for some $M>0$.  Then $\displaystyle z(a)-z(0) = \int_0^a z^\prime(x)\ dx \leq \int_0^a M = Ma$, so $z(x) \leq Mx+z(0)$.  As $z(0) > 0$, we get $(M+z(0))^2 > M(M+z(0)) + z(0) \geq z(M+z(0))$, a contradiction.

Comment: How did you know where to start?

Comment: The two main ways to relate a function and its derivative are the mean value theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus.  For instance, for the MVT approach, I knew I was going to find $z^\prime(c) = \frac{z(x)-z(0)}{x}$ (the choice of $0$ for one endpoint is because that's easiest to deal with), so I just needed to choose $x$ large enough to get good lower bounds on that value.  That's how I chose $x>z(0)$.